# PopupWindow animation not working

Tags: android, android-animation

I has a nice PopupWindow which I want to appear with an animation. I do it like this:

```
popup.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.appear);
popup.showAtLocation(popupMenuLayout, gravity, offsetX, offsetY);
```

I then set up a listener for changing the animation:

```
popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener(){
 @Override
 public void onDismiss(){
  popup.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.disappear);
 }      
});
```

But, hey, it won't work. Neither for res/anim/appear:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromYDelta="100%"
 android:toYDelta="0"
 android:duration="1000" 
/>
```

Nor for res/anim/disappear:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromYDelta="0"
 android:toYDelta="100%"
 android:duration="1000"
/>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Actually, `PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle` expects a style with 2 entries. You'll need to have two xmls, each containing a `<set>`, one for showing and the other for hiding the window. When this is done, put the following piece into values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AnimationPopup">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
</style>
```

and set your animation style to `R.style.AnimationPopup`. That'll do.

I've got this information from https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D the documentation didn't seem to mention it.

**Update:**

An update to Android SDK in 2012 have changed XML syntax. The original `@android:windowEnterAnimation` now became `android:windowEnterAnimation`. So this answer is updated accordingly.

Comment: How about accepting this as the answer if it has helped you. So that someone else could easily get to know that this works.

Comment: One error in your sample : it should be "android:windowEnterAnimation" and not "@android:windowEnterAnimation"

Same for windowExitAnimation

Comment: The Android documentation is really lame at some points, thank you for that very good input!